# 'global' not working in wordpress?

Tags: php, globals

My wordpress theme consists of the file `loop.php` which just does this:
`<?php include("AAAA.php"); ?>`. Now AAAA.php looks like this:

```
<?php
  $test = 1;
  function f() {
    global $test;
    echo "inside f: test='$test'";
  }
  echo "outside f: test='$test' ";
  f();
?>
```

Since I referred to $test inside f, I would suspect that f knows thereafter about the value of $test but actually I obtain this:

```
outside f: test='1' inside f: TEST=''
```

I suspect that I am making a very trivial error... Can somebody point it out to me?

Regards, FW.

Comment: This works only if you have included `loop.php` in a global context. Avoid global variables and constants like hell, they are really, really bad code.

Comment: Globals work in WordPress just as in any other PHP, though as toscho states they can be a pain and should be avoided when at all possible. Maybe some of this will help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+global

Answer (score 1):

Don't use globals, but if you must use them you should explicitly declare them as such. Wordpress includes theme files from functions therefor a `$test = 1;` will be evaluated in the context of the function and the variable `$test` will be implicitly declared in the context of the function but not as a global.